# use array elements as an index

Tags: matlab, matrix

Suppose that we have the following array declaration in matrix

```
a=[1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9]
```

which looks  in matlab as usual matrix form

a =

```
 1     2     3
 4     5     6
 7     8     9
```

I am interested how following code works

> `[a  a(a) ]`

here is given of course it's answer from a book

```
 ans =
    1 2 3 1 4 7
    4 5 6 2 5 8
    7 8 9 3 6 9
```

as I understood  first  a in bracket  simply display original  a, or number from 1  to 9, as  a second case is use array elements as index into array, so it means  that for example   numbers

```
1   2  3
4   5  6
7   8   9
```

these are  indexes for  array a, first index  `a[1]=1,a{2]=2,a[3]=3 ....  a[9]=9`  is this right? But why does it print   in transpose manner? Should not be  like the original matrix? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the rows are traversed before the columns so `a[2] = 4`, `a[3] = 7` and `a[4] = 2`

Comment: so  how can i distinguish  when will be first traversed rows and when columns?

Comment: That is the rule in Matlab. When you use only one index into a bidimensional matrix it will always traverse first the rows.